# Space between notification bar and Toolbar

Tags: android, flutter, dart, adb

Hi I have bean create a new Flutter project, but in some screen sizes the notification bar and the Toolbar has a space between it self, how can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: Does it occur in specific devices or all the devices?

Comment: That happens on devices with medium or large screens

Comment: Can you please share the code snippet? Otherwise it's difficult to analyze the issue.